# convert list of key/value strings into map python

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

Convert list of key/value strings into map. Assume that the list contains only strings and that each string has exactly one ':' .

Is the following code a good approach? Does anyone know of a more elegant solution to this?

```
>>> l = ['name:number']
>>> l = {x[:x.find(':')] : x[x.find(':')+1:] for x in l}
>>> print(l)
{'name': 'number'}
```

Comment: If it works it can't be stupid... However I would just use `split(':')`

Comment: @OferSadan - yea that's clearer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

An even simpler approach:

```
>>> l = ['name:number']
>>> dict(x.split(':') for x in l)
{'name': 'number'}
```